# "Module" is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-modules

I have an application with some modules.

Here is my root module:

```
// imports...

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppModule ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ...APP_PIPES // Array with my pipes
    ],
    imports: [ // import Angular's modules
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),
        ...APP_MODULES, // Array with my modules
        ...THIRD_PARTY_MODULES // Array with libs modules
    ],
    providers: [ // expose our Services and Providers into Angular's dependency injection
        ENV_PROVIDERS,
        APP_PROVIDERS
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
 ...
}
```

And here's **ONE** of my *common* modules:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { MenuComponent } from './menu.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ MenuComponent ],
    exports: [ MenuComponent ],
    imports: [ CommonModule ],
    providers: [ ]
})

export class MenuModule {
  ...
}
```

I thought it's the correct way to do this, however I'm getting the following error:

> AppModule is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been
>   imported into your module

I searched for AppModule in my whole application and I'm using only it in my `app.module.ts`.

Am I missing to import/export something? Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
bootstrap: [ AppModule ],
```

should be

```
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
```

Here you need to pass the `AppModule`

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```